# Java program downloading wrong static image from Google

Tags: java

My Java program downloads static map images from Google maps which shows the route line. If I go to this [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=enc:c%7ButHdfqJJaA%60AoI%5CoATo@Xe@P[R_@NYFYHs@AGAQDe@LYHGNCF?h@[Za@bBuDtA_Dp@gAR[J[@i@?SF]FIJEJAj@m@f@iAbByDlQoa@Pm@By@CS?YBSFOHKLCXOr@SbE%7DG~@gBfAiBdH_MjAwBFa@j@_ARYQg@kAkDIBIEEI?M@GMMQYgBiEaD%7BHJOH[%60Hy%60@d@iC%7BCgBgEcC%7DCeBb@gC) in my browser, I get the correct image which is a map with directional polyline.

But when I download the image from the same URL with my Java program, I get this instead:

[image]

Both URLs look the same to me, I can't work out what's wrong. Here is my code if anyone can spot something out of place?

Code:

```
try {
    String mapImgUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x300&path=enc:" + polyline + "&key=AIzaSyBn2qYJcHoNCgNQZv1mcycnUo06sJDZPBs";
    String imageFileName = houseNumber + " " + address + ".jpg";

    URL url = new URL(mapImgUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();

    ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon((new ImageIcon(imageFileName))
            .getImage().getScaledInstance(400, 400, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JLabel labelMap = new JLabel();
            labelMap.setIcon(imgIcon);
            panelMap.add(labelMap);
        }
    });
```

The polyline data is correct, I have compared the data I get from the JSON in my browser with the data I get from my program, and they match. This is the polyline data straight from the API if it helps anyway:

```
c{utHdfqJJaA`AoI\\oATo@Xe@P[R_@NYFYHs@AGAQDe@LYHGNCF?h@[Za@bBuDtA_Dp@gAR[J[@i@?SF]FIJEJAj@m@f@iAbByDlQoa@Pm@By@CS?YBSFOHKLCXOr@SbE}G~@gBfAiBdH_MjAwBFa@j@_ARYQg@kAkDIBIEEI?M@GMMQYgBiEaD{HJOH[`Hy`@d@iC{CgBgEcC}CeBb@gC
```

Comment: Have compared your URL to the link are confirmed they are the exact same URL?

Comment: Are you URL encoding the polyline? I tried it un-url encoded and got the "earth" image, as you did

Comment: The polyline is just saved as a String, I don't know if it is URL encoded or not, how can I check/make sure it is encoded?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is you haven't URL encoded the poly line.

Use:  `java.net.URLEncoder`

```
String mapImgUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x300&path=enc:"
  + URLEncoder.encode(polyline, "utf-8") + "&key=<key>";
```

Note the `encode(String)` method which doesn't require the character encoding is deprecated. Also, make sure you import from the public package, `java.net`

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it just results in no image file being created at all.

Comment: @jb2003 Compare the mapImgUrl `String` with the url you pasted in this question. If they're not identical something else is wrong

Comment: I printed the URL in the console and the polyline portion just says null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The polyline portion of the URL was null due to the thread that gets the polyline data not finishing before the thread that sets up the URL started. I solved this by joining the threads.